# Manually put Image Data to Plist file using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, image, plist

I want to put an Image in a plist file. Programmatically it is easy to save images as data in plist files, but I want to preset the data entry manually. 
How can I put these data with my xcode plist editor in the data field?

Comment: This is a binary plist isn't it?

Comment: Why don't you name those image file same as you key. then access it using that name.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how to do it in code, write some temporary code to write the desired image to a temp plist file. Then you can copy the entry into the real plist file.

However, I'd suggest a different approach. Store the actual image in the app's resource bundle and put the filename in the plist file. This will be so much easier to maintain and update.

Comment: that's what I wanted to avoid, is there no chance to put HEX Data or something in this field?

Comment: Yes, plist files can contain binary data (since you can store `NSData`). Other than writing the `NSData` of the image via code, I have no idea how you would stick image data in a plist file by hand through Xcode. Doing it in code is less than 5 or 6 lines. It would be quicker than typing this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to get the binary data of the image you want to have in the property list, and then input it in the file.

I wouldn't recommend it though. You can easily achieve this programmatically, if you need help with the code, i can help you